How do I align a column on a decimal point in an xltabular environment?
I have a landscape, long table with different column types specified, as in tabularx. I am using the xltabular package, as it seems the perfect combination of longtable and tabularx that I require.
However, I am trying to centre custom columns (or, even the X column, if possible) on the decimal point. I have tried a few variants of both dcolumn and siunitx work-arounds but I can't manage to get the solution. Any help would be appreciated!
MWE:
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4]{article}

\usepackage{xltabular,pdflscape,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hyphenpenalty10000\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{XXY}
\caption{Table}\label{table1}\\
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% Head
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Title}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% Body
123.45 & 67.89 & 12.34\\
56.78 & 912.00 & 345.67\\
891.23 & 45.67 & 89.12\\
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{center}

\end{document}


(1) there is no paper=a4 option, use a4paper, (2) see the siunitx package and use its S column instead of the X and Y columns.

Using xltabular does not make sense for a table with such narrow columns. Just use longtable instead. If you extend the column widths extremely the tables would become unreadable. Only use xltabular if you not only have number columns, but also text columns that need line breaks. Use X (or your Y) only for those text columns.
